# How to call Azure Rest API in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-rest-api

I'm new to C# world. I have a project where I need to collect Azure compute usage quotas across all regions from 700+ subscriptions. I have done it easily using PowerShell (Get-AzVMUsage).

I have to do it using C#. I guess I need to use Rest API for it. (I am open to another way to achieve this).

Azure Rest API: `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/usages?api-version=2019-12-01`

How can I fetch results using the above Rest API? Once I get results from this Rest API, I can put my business logic on top of it to perform data aggregations and loop it through 700+ Subscriptions and dump the data in SQL-MI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from [Vinny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61965759/33) is longer supported. As of December 2022 `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` Nuget which is used with `AuthenticationContext` is no longer supported.

We can use the `Azure.Identity` Nuget and then replace the GetAccessToken method with this...

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientKey)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Begin GetAccessToken");

    var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientKey);
    var result = await credentials.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }), CancellationToken.None);
    return result.Token;
}
```

That said it may be easier to use the SDKs. I have written a [blog post on both the SDKs and Rest APIs](https://www.blueboxes.co.uk/how-to-use-azure-management-apis-in-c-with-azure.identity) that you may find useful.

Comment: it would be amazing if you could include the using statements here too... they always throw me off.

Answer (score 7):

I Google'ed and figured out the way from below url.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/how-to-securely-connect-to-azure-from-c-and-run-rest-apis[MSDN Forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/how-to-securely-connect-to-azure-from-c-and-run-rest-apis)

```html
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AzureCapacityUsage
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {            
            try 
            {
                string token = await GetAccessToken(TenantID,ClientID,Password); 
                await GetResults(token);              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetResults(string token)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
            };

            string URI = $"{SubscriptionGUID}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{Region}/usages?api-version=2019-12-01";

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI);

            var HttpsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var JSONObject =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(HttpsResponse);
            
            Console.WriteLine(JSONObject);
            var JSONObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(JSONObject);
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();

        }
        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientKey)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Begin GetAccessToken");

            string authContextURL = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId;
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientKey);
            var result = await authenticationContext

            .AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential);
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }
            string token = result.AccessToken;
            return token;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a more up to date answer, see the John's post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964132/how-to-call-azure-rest-api-in-c-sharp#answer-74797583

Answer (score -2):

`System.Net.HttpClient` is your friend here :

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class SampleCall
    {
        static async Task<string> CallApi()
        {
            var subscriptionId = "subscriptionIdHere";
            var location = "locationHere";
            var uri = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/usages?api-version=2019-12-01";

            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var content = await SampleCall.CallApi();
```

Comment: Where is the auth component of this, it is essential